# How to display more than one posts in single-article.twig?

Tags: php, wordpress, symfony, twig, timber

I'm new to twig and timber and I'm trying to show more than one post in single-article.twig.
I've already registered a custom post type, and displayed all the posts in the page template "page-articles.twig". When a specific post is being clicked on, it opened a "single-article.twig", that will always be shown first at the top and as a whole article. Bellow the article should appear 2 most recent posts like Read more...

I tried this in single.php:

```
$context = Timber::get_context();
$post = Timber::query_post();
$context['post'] = $post;

$query = array(
  'post_type' => 'articles',
  'posts_per_page' => 3
);
$articles = new Timber\PostQuery($query);
$context['articles_posts'] = $articles;

Timber::render( array( 'single-' . $post->ID . '.twig', 'single-' . 
$post->post_type . '.twig', 'single.twig' ), $context );
```

and this in single-article.twig:

```
{% for article in articles_posts %}
   {# do stuff #}
{% endfor %}
```

As I mentioned, it is necessary to display 3 posts, of which one is the main, and 2 "smaller" that look like Read more...

Comment: What isn't working?

Comment: Posts are being displayed but when I click on any of the two Read more posts it leads me only on the "main/central"  post

Comment: What do you do in the `{# do stuff #}` part of your Twig file?

Comment: Basic stuff like {{ article.title }}, {{ article.date }}, {{ article.content }}, {{ article.link }}...

Comment: @DjordjoS does the answer below help?

Answer (score 0):

Is getting the link to the articles_posts the only problem you are having? I have done pretty much exactly this and it is working for me although I think I might've encountered a similar problem with the link. Might need to see everything in the do stuff section as it may have something going on there. Otherwise, perhaps try using this as a workaround:

single-article.twig

```
    {% for article in articles_posts %}
        <a href="{{site.url ~ '/article/' ~ article.slug}}" class="related__project">
            link to article (assuming your custom post type slug is article)
        </a>
    {% endfor %}
```